# Unable to add object to nsmutable array in singleton

Tags: ios, ios6, nsmutablearray, singleton

The same code works on iOS 5 but not in iOS 6. That is the count shows as being 0. Any ideas?
It should say atleast 1 as the count since I have verified house.png to be a valid image.

Here is my code:

```
MyManager * myManager = [MyManager sharedInstance];
                NSString *pathOfImageFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"house" ofType:@"png"];
                UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathOfImageFile];

                UIImageView * tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
                [myManager.assets addObject:tempImageView];

                NSLog(@"image count: %d", [myManager.assets count]);
```

Here is my singleton:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MyManager : NSObject
{

    MyManager *_sharedObject;
    NSMutableArray * assets;


}

//Property Listing
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString * postTitle;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString * postText;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString * postLink;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString * postCategory;
//assets
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * assets;


+ (id)sharedInstance;
- (void)reset;



@end





#import "MyManager.h"

@implementation MyManager

//Property Listing
@synthesize postTitle=_postTitle;
@synthesize postText=_postText;
@synthesize postLink=_postLink;
@synthesize postCategory=_postCategory;
@synthesize assets=_assets;


- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if ( self )
    {
         assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"Singleton Initialized...");
    }
    return self;
}




+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    __strong static id _sharedObject = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init]; // or some other init method
    });
    return _sharedObject;
}



- (void)reset
{

    self.postTitle =@"";
    self.postText=@"";
    self.postLink=@"";
    self.postCategory=@"";
    [self.assets removeAllObjects];
}


@end
```

Comment: That's weird.
Maybe house.png isn't in the target ? 
are you sure the image is still in the 'copy bundle resources' phase ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have extra ivars related to your `assets` property.

You define a property named `assets`. You then (needlessly) synthesize the property specifying that the generated ivar should be named `_assets`.

You also (needlessly) declare an explicit ivar named `assets`.

In your `init` method you assign the array to the `assets` ivar. In your `reset` method you clear the `assets` property (using the `_assets` ivar).

Get rid of the explicit `assets` ivar. Get rid of the `@synthesize` statement. This will leave you with an auto generated ivar of `_assets`.

Update your code to use either the property or the `_assets` ivar.

Comment: yes you are correct. When I did  _assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; it worked fine. Funny thing is the same code worked on ios 5. I will fix my code appropriately.

Comment: I got rid of the NSMutableArray * assets; and am using self.assets in the singleton now

Comment: The version of iOS has nothing to do with this. It's possible it may have worked differently with an older version of the compiler (from older versions of Xcode) but even then, given the exact code, there should be no way it ever worked. It would have worked as-is if you just removed the `@synthesize` line.

Comment: You are correct. i just checked and I was using "@synthesize assets" and not "@synthesize assets=_assets" which I tweaked in this app. Thanks much gentlemen (or ladies)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 _assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

And you are defining sharedObject in your interface as a property: `MyManager *_sharedObject;`

You don't want that if you'll always grab your instance via `[MyManager sharedInstance];` which is holding the initialized instance in that local static var.